# Writable Stream empties the file but do not write expected content in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodejs-stream

This is my code to get an array of records and write them as CSV string one by one in a file. I cannot get the writable stream to write in the file. It just erases whatever is in the file and does not write the new data in.

```js
const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(process.env.SAVED_FILE);
const transformStream = new Stream.Transform({
    writableObjectMode: true,
    readableObjectMode: true,
})
transformStream._transform = (chunk, encoding, callback) => {
    console.log(chunk);
    transformStream.push("\"" + chunk.join("\",\"") + "\"");
    callback();
}
const readable = new Stream.Readable({objectMode: true})
    .pipe(transformStream)
    .pipe(writeStream);
let records = [["a", "b"], [1, 2], ["c", "d"], [8, 9]];
records.forEach(record => readable.push(record));
readable.push(null);

writeStream.on("error", function (err) {
    console.log("there is an error!")
});
writeStream.on("end", function () {
    console.log("reached the end of the stream!")
});
```

Any help appreciated on this basic example !

Comment: `createWriteStream` creates a stream that by default writes *at the beginning of the file*, effectively replacing it: http://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options explains the `start` and `flags` options, specifically that by default the file is replaced (`flags` is `w` by default) and `start` is (possibly) implied to be zero by default.

Comment: `res.send("Data Saved");` :: where is `res` defined?

Comment: res is the result that node will send back to the user - standard node but not useful here indeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pipe()` method returns the destination stream, i.e. the writable stream.

In your code,

```
const readable = new Stream.Readable({objectMode: true})
    .pipe(transformStream)
    .pipe(writeStream);
```

`readable` doesn't contains a reference to a readable stream like you expect. Instead, it refers to the last stream in the chain, i.e. `writeStream` and you cannot call `push` on a writable stream.

Change your code as shown below:

```
const readable = new stream.Readable({ objectMode: true });

readable
  .pipe(transformStream)
  .pipe(writeStream);
```

Comment: Thank you very much it works !
another question if you have 2 minutes: my "end" event on the `writeStream` never gets triggered. How should I handle that ? I thought pushing "null" to a readable stream triggered the "end" event immediately ?

Comment: Writable streams don't have an event named `end` (readable streams do). Writable streams have a `close` event.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now i'll go read the fricking docs...